# Complete Noob: Can't get PyDev working in Eclipse Oxygen with Mint KDE 18.2 OS

Tags: eclipse, pydev, eclipse-marketplace

I am not a programmer, but want to learn and wanted to use Eclipse Oxygen to run PyDev, and I have tried tutorials and tried many things. I use Linux Mint KDE 18.2 and I did at least attempt to set up Java, but for some reason, the python options are not appearing in Eclipse in the Window->Preferences location. I'm lost to what to do and where to get help. I am also only 6 months in on using Linux.

Also, I can't seem to get marketplace onto eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the java version you're using is too old (i.e.: not java 8) or you're installing PyDev as a regular user and Eclipse was installed as admin...

As a note, an easy way around would be just getting LiClipse (http://liclipse.com), which has PyDev builtin (it's Eclipse + PyDev + some other goodies -- although it's commercial, there's a trial period for you to experiment).

Comment: I did install java 8, so maybe it's the latter. I'm trying to install pycharm instead, and software manager seems stuck at 99% of install, waiting...

Comment: Albeit you installed java 8, are you sure that Eclipse is using it? (check the help > about > installation details > configuration to see the java actually being used) -- for the second case, have you tried running Eclipse as root and installing there (or create a new install under your own user using the Platform Runtime Binary as a base as recommended in http://www.pydev.org/download.html).

Comment: Ok, for a first try at this sort of thing, it went poorly, something hosed my OS install and because of that, and the fact that I had another unrelated issue, I did a fresh install and upon advice, put PyCharm on my fresh install and it's running fine as far as I can tell.

So that leads to this question:

Would I hose my system putting LiClipse or Eclipse on my system also, I know that dependency conflicts can occur.

My Chosen OS is GNU/Linux Mint KDE 18.2 (for now, it's going to have to be Cinnamon later on, as many of you know, KDE is going to be dropped over time).

Comment: If you don't use the system package manager there's no reason for the system to get hosed... just download LiClipse (http://www.liclipse.com/download.html) and extract it in the desktop and it should be good to go -- java and PyDev are builtin. If you go bare bones Eclipse you have to make sure you have a recent version of Oracle VM and have to manually install PyDev (get the Eclipse Platform runtime binary from http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads and follow instructions from http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html)..